# How can I populate my HTML table with an array of data?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I'm building a table with HTML and then have created a function which allows me to select a cell. I also have a text field, with a function which will both change the innerText of the cell to the value in the text field **and** push that value into an array of the data in each table cell. I am then saving it to localStorage.

Here I encounter my error: how can I properly retrieve the data from the localStorage variable and repopulate the table with the values in the array?

Here's my code

*omitting the table creation, textEntering, functions because they appear to be working fine*

```
function save() {
  localStorage.setItem("tblArrayJson", JSON.stringify(tblArray));
  document.getElementById("lblInfo").innerHTML = "Spreadsheet saved.";
}
```

This is working because in a test function I can print the `tblArrayJson` in an alert. Next I am trying to load the data back to the table:

```
function loadSheet() {
  var loadedData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("tblArrayJson"));
  var loadedTable = document.getElementById("SpreadsheetTable");
  var currRow, cell;
  alert("the retrieved JSON string contains: " + loadedData);

  for (var i = 0; currRow = loadedTable.rows[i]; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; cell = currRow.cells[j]; j++) {
      cell.innerHTML = loadedData.shift();
    }
  }
}
```

The alert displaying the loadedData is working correctly. So what is it about my loop that is failing to insert the array values back into the table? They just stay blank.

Is there a problem with the way I'm using the function? Here is my button with the onclick:

```
<input id="btnLoad" type="button" onclick="loadSheet();" value="Load" />
```

Comment: your for loop looks incorrect

Comment: Your loop is incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

`localStorage` is an **object**.

A loop through an object `for(var key in object) {}` is **different** to a loop through an array `for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i += 1) {}`.

If the data looks like

```
var loadedData = {
    0: ["cell1", "cell2", "cell3"],
    1: ["cell1", "cell2", "cell3"]
}
```

the loops should look like

```
for(var key in loadedData) {
    var row = loadedTable.insertRow();
    for(var i = 0; i < loadedData[key].length; i += 1) {
        var cell = row.insertCell(i);
        cell.innerHTML = loadedData[key][i];
    }
}
```

**Example**

```js
var loadedData = {
  0: ["cell1", "cell2", "cell3"],
  1: ["cell1", "cell2", "cell3"]
}

function loadSheet() {
  //var loadedData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("tblArrayJson"));
  var loadedTable = document.getElementById("SpreadsheetTable");

  for (var key in loadedData) {
    var row = loadedTable.insertRow();
    for (var i = 0; i < loadedData[key].length; i += 1) {
      var cell = row.insertCell(i);
      cell.innerHTML = loadedData[key][i];
    }
  }
}


loadSheet();
```

```html
<table id="SpreadsheetTable"></table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `for` loop is missing the terminating condition. I added that to mine, you're free to modify to fit your needs.

```js
var data = {
  0: ["cell1", "cell2", "cell3"],
  1: ["cell4", "cell5", "cell6"]
};

// localStorage.tblArrayJson = JSON.stringify(loadedData);

function loadSheet() {
  // var data = JSON.parse(localStorage.tblArrayJson);
  var table = document.getElementById("SpreadsheetTable");
  var row, cell;
  
  // Used Object.keys() to get an array of all keys in localStorage
  for (var key of Object.keys(data)) {
    row = table.insertRow();
    
    for (var i = 0; i < data[key].length; i++) {
      cell = row.insertCell(i);
      cell.innerHTML = data[key][i];
    }
  }
}

loadSheet();
```

```html
<table id="SpreadsheetTable"></table>
```

Comment: how can i have 4 elements in my loop conditions? this is not working and my intellisense is telling me it's incorrect...

Comment: Kindly recheck answer.